# Sqoop ExportTool to Oracle NullPointer Exception

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

Using command like:

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:'@somehostname.com:1521/prod1_adhoc' \
--username fbaggins \
--P \
--table MIDDLEEARTH \
--hcatalog-database MORDOR \
--hcatalog-table MORDOR \
--columns IS_DWARF,IS_ELF \
--verbose
```

Results in this error:

```
16/08/25 10:08:31 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://somehostname.com:1521
16/08/25 10:08:31 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
16/08/25 10:08:31 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@56aac163
16/08/25 10:08:31 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
16/08/25 10:08:31 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@somehostname.com:1521/prod1_adhoc/fbaggins
```

Not sure where the null is coming from as there are no nulls in the Hive table.

For reference, from hive:

```
hive> describe MORDOR;
OK
IS_DWARF bigint                                      
IS_ELF   string
```

From Oracle:

```
describe MORDOR
Name                    Null Type        
----------------------- ---- ----------- 
IS_DWARF                     NUMBER(12)  
IS_ELF                       VARCHAR2(3)
```

Comment: *"NullPointerException ... Not sure where the null is coming from as there are no nulls in the Hive table"* -- your sense of humor reminds me of the Monty Python *(or maybe the Monty Java would be more appropriate)*

Answer (score 1):

Is MORDOR a Hive view and not actually a table?

I have exactly the same problem when an object specified for sqoop --table is a view. DESCRIBE commands just prints columns of that view - so it does not show if it's a view or not. You could run `SHOW CREATE TABLE MORDOR` to confirm that's a view or table ("show create **table**" works for a view too as there is no separate command like "`show create view`").

SQOOP documentation explicitly states that **sqoop import** from a view is supported, but sqoop documentation on **sqoop export** for a view is silent - it's not stated if it's supported or not - it might be a SQOOP or HMS bug. Sqoop might not like what HMS returns for a view. So not exluding it might be an HMS bug.

Comment: Even Im facing similar issue.I'm using Hive view in Sqoop export job. Whats the workaround u did? Did you create hive table instead? In my case i have created hive view on hive-hbase table because we have Struct datatype . Any suggestions would appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We had to export from a table and not a view. I am not aware of any workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logs again: don't you see anything absurd?

> Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://**$HOSTNAME:$PORT**
>   Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@$HOST:$PORT/$ALIAS/$SCHEMA

Yes. **The bloody environment variables** (or shell variables) **have not been resolved by the shell**. Although I'm not sure what happened to the Metastore URI (it's defined in a Hadoop conf file, no shell/env variables there...)

That's because **you have enclosed them in SINGLE QUOTES**.
`--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:'@$HOST:$PORT/$ALIAS'`

So you have a 3-step solution:

1. use double quotes whenever you want the shell to resolve variables inside
2. learn script shell
3. learn about pointers, Null pointers, and what happens when some buggy code fails to check whether an Object variable has been properly initialized (i.e. `NullPointerException` in Java)

Comment: Samson, I purposefully put variables in to protect sharing of sensitive data in a public forum.  I assure you that what goes in those spaces is an actual value (e.g. thrift://db21.mydomain.com:1521, and same for all other spaces).